# Relate models via Foreign Key using a string field (CharField)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have an API which has two models. These models I would like to relate with a Foreign Key. Then, I want to send data, more specifically I want to send a string. If this string matches the name of the foreign key I want to create an instance. Like so:

```
class Simulation(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    project                 = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1, related_name="projects")
```

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

I send data like so:

```
def test_api_local(method='get', data={}):

    r = requests.request(method, ENDPOINT , data=data, headers=headers)
    return r

test_api_local(method="post", data={"user":2, "project":1 })
```

Ok so that works. Like that I create an instance with the data. But what I would like to do, is to send the name of my project as a string and create a simulation object that has the name of my project in it. But right now I can only send integers.

I tried setting the name of the project as a primary key, but I get a multiple key error. I tried setting it to unique, but it is also not working.

I read that it is not advisable to use strings as foreign key, since it breaks generic foreign keys. But then, is there a way to do that? I think that has to work somehow, but I don't know anymore...

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to look up the project to use when creating the Simulation instance:

```
project, created = Project.objects.get_or_create(name=project_name)
Simulation.objects.create(project=project, user=some_user)
```

Also on your `Simulation.project` field, the `related_name` should be `simulations`. The related_name is the field that is accessible from the model the foreign key points to, so in this case it would exist on Project. With your version it's `project_instance.projects` where projects is a collection of simulations. It makes more sense if it were `project_instance.simluations`.